# Uploading Files instead of Zipfile?

Tags: zappa

EDIT: Zappa does not use EC2 and not Beanstalk, but Amazon Api Services.
So probably there ist no way.

---

I have a question for Zappa EC2 Serverless Services.

Launching `zappa update dev` creates one Zip-File and uploads this. Because my upload is slow, it would be great to have ability to upload only changed files, especially in the beginning (config files etc) of a project. Every single file change needs 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. There is no way.

---

I had the same problem (slow home upload) and ~solved it so that I'm deploying through a CI system (that has a much much faster upload).

If you are deploying an open source app you can use [Circle CI's free tier for open source](https://circleci.com/pricing/) or for *closed* source you can take advantage of [Gitlab's free CI offering](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/).

---

Here [is my Circle CI config file](https://github.com/mislavcimpersak/xkcd-excuse-generator/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) for my open source project.

It took me 2-3 minutes to just upload .zip from my local computer, now it takes less than a minute to run all the tests and deploy.

For me, the main advantage is that I don't have to nervously watch shell for the next few minutes and can just continue with my work.